# Why would /etc/passwd be used every time someone executes `ls -l` command?

Tags: ls, passwd

Read from *APUE*, just feel curious:

> The password file is used every time a user logs in to a
>   UNIX system and every time someone executes an `ls -l` command.

Comment: FYI I try `strace ls -l` later on, I see a `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4` statement.

Comment: Of course, reality is more complex nowadays.  It's not `/etc/passwd` on the BSDs.  An active `nscd` will change things; as will the NSS.  So note that this question is based upon a 7th Edition worldview.

Comment: @JdeBP *Ancient Programming in the Unix Environment*, then?

Comment: @JdeBP [It isn't?](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=passwd&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+13-current&arch=default&format=html) I wa surprised when you said that because I'd think that a lot of programs (scripts and binaries) would break which rely (perhaps wrongly, but still) on the presence of /etc/passwd.

Comment: It isn't, as reading that manual page properly, including its FILES section, will reveal.  (-:

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The file-system directly associates the numerical UID (User ID) and GID (Group ID) values with the file, not the user name and group name (which are strings). So the `ls -l` command (and any other command that displays the user and group owner of a file) need to get the user and group names from somewhere. The `/etc/passwd` file is one such source (probably the original and most common source). The manual bears this out - from [PASSWD (5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) (i.e. the man page for the `/etc/passwd` file):

> many utilities, like ls(1) use it to map user IDs to usernames

Comment: To complement the answer: POSIX specifies option `-n` for `ls`. This prevents translation of UIDs and GIDs to usernames and group names. I have tested `ls -n` with GNU core utils' `ls` and the option prevented accessing both `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` as expected.